# How to declare postgresql json/jsonb field with sequel?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm stuck with that. Can't find anywhere in docs how to declare such spatial data types as inet and jsonb or json.

ruby 2.4.1, sequel 4.47

Plain ruby script with `require 'sequel'`.

Declaration such as

```
DB.create_table :requests do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key :client_id, :clients
  foreign_key :service_id, :services
  DateTime :created_at, null: false
  DateTime :answered_at, null: false
  JsonBType :request, null: false
end
```

Comment: Are you refering to the postgres docs? Are you using rails? or are you trying to add a row through the psql console?

Comment: Did that work? Did you get an error? If so, what was the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the alternative way of defining columns by using the **column** method - details can be found [here](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/schema_modification_rdoc.html). In your example this becomes:

```
DB.create_table :requests do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key :client_id, :clients
  foreign_key :service_id, :services
  DateTime :created_at, null: false
  DateTime :answered_at, null: false
  column :request, :jsonb, null: false
end
```